Next.js: Custom Server with Standalone Output
I'm working on a Next.js project where I need to CRT, which requires using a custom server. I've created a server.js file for this purpose. However, I also want to use the output: 'standalone' option in my next.config.js for optimized builds.
The issue is that when I build the project with output: 'standalone', it creates its own server.js file, which conflicts with my custom server.
I've attempted to manually copy my server.js into the .next/standalone directory after building, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or how to properly configure it to work with the standalone build.
Any guidance on how to properly set this up would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Update the scripts in the package.json file, then your custom server.js can copied automatically.
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node server.js",
  "build": "next build && cp server.js .next/standalone",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node .next/standalone/server.js",
  // Your other scripts...
}


Thank you, but if I do as you said, can't I use standalone?

Or cource you can use standalone. Standalone Output was configured inside next.config.js, its's not conflict with updating scripts in the package.json file.

Well, I didn't understand, but isn't the script changed to a custom server file? Throw away the existing standalone server.js file and
